# Problem with this limit! $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos((n+1)x)e^{nx}}{\cos(nx)e^{(n+1)x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have trouble with this limit.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos((n+1)x)e^{nx}}{\cos(nx)e^{(n+1)x}}$$

I tried this:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos((n+1)x)e^{nx}}{\cos(nx)e^{(n+1)x}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos(nx+x)}{\cos(nx)e}=\frac{1}{e} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos(nx+x)}{\cos(nx)}$$

But I can't solve the last part. Can someone help me?

Comment: That last limit does not exist, unless $x=0$.

Comment: $$ \frac {e^{nx}}{e^{(n+1)x}} = \frac 1 {e^x} \ne \frac 1 e. $$

Comment: $$ \frac{ \cos(nx+x) }{\cos(nx)} = \frac{\cos(nx)\cos x - \sin(nx)\sin x}{\cos(nx)} = \cos x - \tan(nx)\sin x. $$

Comment: If $x = k\pi$, the limit does exist.